# Selenium Element

Tags: selenium, dynamic, webdriver

Not able to select a dynamic drop down PFB the html tag of the element.

Drop down dynamic ids:

1. page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:1:ServiceSubtype
2. page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:2:ServiceSubtype

HTML Code :

```
<td class="dataCell" style="border-top:1px solid #838282;">
<span id="page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:1:DescPopup" class="DescServicePopupClone" style="display:none;"></span>
<span id="page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:1:DescPopupHasResource" class="DescServicePopupHasResource" style="display:none;"></span>
<span id="page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:1:DescPopupLOE" class="DescServicePopupLOE" style="display:none;"></span>
```

My code:

```
 new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@id, 'page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:')]"))).selectByVisibleText("CAT-New Implementer");
    Thread.sleep(18000);
```

getting the below error:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(@id,
>   'page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:')]"} For documentation on this
>   error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

UPDATE from OP - part of the "real" HTML:

```
<select id="page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:2:ServiceSubtype" name="page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:2:ServiceSubtype"> 
<option value="">--None--</option> 
<option value="CAT-New Implementer">CAT-New Implementer</option> 
<option value="CAT-Repeat Implementer">CAT-Repeat Implementer</option> </select> </span> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[starts-with(@id, 'page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:')]"))).selectByVisibleText("CAT-New Implementer");
```

I also changed "contains" to "starts-with" because that better suits your example.

Comment: ... Hi Thanks for your reply. but now m getting the below error:                          org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "td"                                                             i used the xpath in the below code:                                                                                           new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(@id, 'page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:')]/ancestor::td[1]"))).selectByVisibleText("CAT-New Implementer");

Comment: @HinaNaz you cannot use the Select class on elements other than HTML selects (with options) -> updated my answer -> you should probably update your question, what you actually want to achieve because your span elements do not contain a "visible text" CAT-New Implementer

Comment: Hi its a drop down field and i want to select a value from the drop down.  here is the full HTML code                                                                              <select id="page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:2:ServiceSubtype" name="page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:2:ServiceSubtype">
<option value="">--None--</option>
<option value="CAT-New Implementer">CAT-New Implementer</option>
<option value="CAT-Repeat Implementer">CAT-Repeat Implementer</option>
</select>
</span>
</td>

Comment: it is still not working now m getting the error that the text is not visible and when i tried with selectBy index its geving the error that   Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 91 milliseconds. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have more than 3 pages to automate and all pages are having element with dynamic value am not sure how to handle this situation. your help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to not use XPath.  Prefer ID, then maybe name, and then CSS Selectors. Those 3 locators should be 99% of your find methods. XPath is complex, fragile, and slow. Stick to the simple things until you get them mastered and then move on to XPath when you absolutely must.

This code should work

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:2:ServiceSubtype")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("CAT-New Implementer");
```

Since you have an ID on the `SELECT`, use that. Because it is a `SELECT`, casting the `WebElement` to a `Select` gets you extra options only available for `SELECT`s as far as choosing `OPTION`s. For your example, you can use either `.selectByVisibleText()` or `.selectByValue()` since they are equivalent in the HTML you provided.

---

EDIT 1

Another option is to look for a partial ID, ID ends with ($) X, but I don't know if that is unique on your page.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[id$=':ServiceSubtype']")));
```

Yet another option is to increment a counter and insert that into your ID string.

```
int i = 0;
Select dropdown2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("page:frm:pageB:repeatUpper:0:repeat:" + i + ":ServiceSubtype")));
// i++; each time you add something
```

Comment: Hi.. id is also dynamic every time i add a value id will shift to +1 like.. reatUpper:0:repeat:2:ServiceSubtype reatUpper:0:repeat:3:ServiceSubtype reatUpper:0:repeat:4:ServiceSubtype not able to use the code more than 1 time id is getting keep changing :(